# Why Does Unity lag Often That I have To Manually Shutdown/Restart my Core i3 Laptop?

Tags: 11.04, laptop

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu then do did some upgrades. After my next restart when I try to open Ubuntu Software Center it took about 20 seconds for the window to load then 10 more seconds before it became click able. While doing some installation of software, Unity lags like hell that every time I click any application it takes a few seconds before I can see it. Even GEdit take a lot of time to load.

The worst part was when I was doing nothing to my computer. Even on that part, my computer lags.

My Laptop is a Brand New Core i3 with 2GB of RAM. Unity should run perfectly on that kind of machine right?

BTW: I reinstalled Ubuntu 11.04 for about 5 times now and still nothing changed.

Comment: I kind of solved the problem. Its UbuntuOne. When I checked it on System Monitor it consumes 1.2Gb of memory. Why is that? Had anyone encountered the same problem as mine?

Comment: To be precise ubuntuone-sync-daemon is the one that eats up more than half of my memory. Is this the reason why people don't use UbuntuOne?

Comment: *ubuntuone-syncdaemon

Answer (score 2):

It's Confirmed! It's Ubuntu One that is responsible for the lag in my laptop. When I removed UbuntuOne in my startup items, I rebooted then my Ubuntu is faster now. The way Ubuntu should be. ^_^